# How does Logstash5.x integrate with Kafka0.10.1.1 can't output message?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, bigdata

Those days I had tried to integrate `Logstash5.x` with `Kafka_0.10.1.1`, after finish ready environment and update settings seems nothings wrong, And check Kafka through console shell scripts, it can produce and consume message. Then start Logstash agent try to collect message, but it start failed, it's full output message like below:

```
[2017-02-04T14:16:51,575][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig] ProducerConfig values: 
        acks = 1
        batch.size = 16384
        block.on.buffer.full = false
        bootstrap.servers = [xxxxx:9093, xxxxxxx:90902]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.id = producer-1
        compression.type = snappy
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        interceptor.classes = null
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 10
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 5
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        timeout.ms = 30000
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

[2017-02-04T14:16:51,820][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
[2017-02-04T14:16:51,830][ERROR][logstash.outputs.kafka   ] Unable to create Kafka producer from given configuration {:kafka_error_message=>org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer}
[2017-02-04T14:16:51,859][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer, :backtrace=>["org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java:338)", "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java:188)", "java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java/lang/reflect/Constructor.java:423)", "RUBY.create_producer(/usr/share/logstash/plugin/logstash-output-kafka/lib/logstash/outputs/kafka.rb:242)", "RUBY.register(/usr/share/logstash/plugin/logstash-output-kafka/lib/logstash/outputs/kafka.rb:178)", "RUBY.register(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:8)", "RUBY.register(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:37)", "RUBY.start_workers(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:229)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)", "RUBY.start_workers(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:229)", "RUBY.run(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:183)", "RUBY.start_pipeline(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:292)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)"]}
[2017-02-04T14:16:51,953][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-02-04T14:16:54,919][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

There had some related info show up:

1. all kinds of version: `Logstash5.2`, `Kafka_0.10.1.1`, `Logstash-output-kafka-6.1.3`
2. Logstash config file:

   input {
   file {
   path => "/data/tmp/*.log"
   start_position => beginning
   codec => "json"
   }
   }

   filter {
   json {
   source => message
   }
   }

   output {
   kafka {
   bootstrap_servers => "test-broker1.sao.so:9093,test-broker2.sao.so:90902"
   topic_id => "logstash-test"
   compression_type => "snappy"
   retries => 5
   message_key => "logstash-test"
   codec => plain {
   format => "%{message}"
   }
   }
   }

So is there something configure error? What can I do now.

Comment: In my opinion the port `90902` should read `9092` instead

Comment: @Val Thanks for your reminding, This is a stupid mistake, I wasn't check carefully.Never show up next time.

Comment: Yeah, now it working as well. I think the `logstash-output-kafka` plugin need some upgrade can make more usefully info for developer.